# Can an anonymous Class access members of its enclosing class?

Tags: java, class, anonymous

Can an anonymous Class in java access members of its enclosing class or the class where it is defined? if so how.

Comment: This is one of those questions that is best answered by simply trying it yourself.

Comment: or reading a tutorial, of which there are thousands.

Comment: Is asking on a forum really more efficient and reliable than just trying it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, here is an example: (Reference - [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html))

```
public class Test{
  private int count=10;
  private Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
       System.out.println(count);
    }
  });
  public static void main(String []args){
      new Test().thread.start();  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can.  just use the relevant member, or use the explicit syntax `Outer.this.<member>`.